# Optional chaining not working for optional protocol requirements

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I'm following [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) from Apple and the optional chaining does not work as expected.

There is a protocol with optional property and function:

```
@objc protocol CounterDataSource {
  optional func incrementForCount(count: Int) -> Int
  optional var fixedIncrement: Int { get }
}
```

A class that conform to above protocol:

```
class ThreeSource: CounterDataSource {
  let fixedIncrement = 3
}
```

And a class with an optional property (dataSource) that conforms to that protocol:

```
@objc class Counter {
  var count = 0
  var dataSource: CounterDataSource?
  func increment() {
    if let amount = dataSource?.incrementForCount?(count) {
        count += amount
    } else if let amount = dataSource?.fixedIncrement {
        count += amount
    }
  }
}
```

Finally when it comes the time to use an instance of Counter, with a non-nil dataSource property, it doesn't behave as expected:

```
var counter = Counter()
counter.dataSource = ThreeSource()
  for _ in 1...4 {
    counter.increment()
    println(counter.count)
  }
```

If I'm not wrong and according to the tutorial, we should get printed 3, 6, 9, 12. But I only get 0, 0, 0, 0.

Here is the optional chaining in class Counter that is expected to be assigning the value 3 (due to the fixedIncrement property in ThreeSource) to amount:

```
        } else if let amount = dataSource?.fixedIncrement {
        count += amount
    }
```

However this is not working and that branch is not executed.

Is there anything wrong in the code? Or is this maybe a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the website version of the iBook content for The Swift Programming Language (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) shows the ThreeSource declared with @objc.  Either doing this or deriving ThreeSource from `NSObject` works.

[image]